# 'xmlstarlet edit' using a variable as XPath

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

When you follow the doc:

```
xmlstarlet edit --help
```

you can read that `--var` can be used to declare a XPath expression as a variable.

Generating moc file:

```
cat<<EOF > /tmp/file.xml
<root>
<elt>x</elt>
<!-- comment -->
<elt>y</elt>
<!-- other comment -->
</root>
EOF
```

This one works, without variables:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var xp '//elt/following::comment()' \
    -a '//elt/following::comment()' -t elem -n p -v 'some new text' \
    -a '//elt/following::comment()' -t elem -n p -v 'some other text' \
/tmp/file.xml
```

This one doesn't edit with variables:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var xp '//elt/following::comment()' \
    -a xp -t elem -n p -v 'some new text' \
    -a xp -t elem -n p -v 'some other text' \
/tmp/file.xml
```

What does I miss to use variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `'$xp'` to reference your variable:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var xp '//elt/following::comment()' \
    -a '$xp' -t elem -n p -v 'some new text' \
    -a '$xp' -t elem -n p -v 'some other text' \
/tmp/file.xml
```

Comment: Not obvious, an example in the doc could have been interesting, thanks

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek It is mentioned in the documentation of the `--var` option in `xmlstarlet select --help`, but the same option has a shortened help text in `xmlstarlet edit --help`. It works the same in `select` as in `edit` though.